# I am getting an error while using an insert query in sql create table #vr_test (x varchar not null ) insert into #vr_test select 'JAMES'

Tags: sql

I am getting an error while using an insert query in sql

```
create table #vr_test (x varchar not null ) ;

insert into #vr_test
    select 'JAMES' ;

error 
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 24
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

could you please help .. thanks in advance

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: The problem is that you didn't open up a search engine and paste in "String or binary data would be truncated."

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you are using SQL Server.  You should *always* include a length when using `varchar()`.  The default length varies by context:

```
create table #vr_test (
    x varchar(255) not null
) ;

insert into #vr_test(x)
    select 'JAMES' ;
```

The default for a type definition is 1 character.  That is why you are getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the VARCHAR field with the number of characters:

```
   create table #vr_test (x varchar(100) not null )    
   insert into #vr_test   select 'JAMES'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in oracle, then following should work:

create table
"#vr_test"
(x varchar2(50));

insert into "#vr_test"
    select 'JAMES' from dual;

select * from "#vr_test";